# How can I use PIL to crop a select area based on face detection?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, face-detection

Hi I am wanting to use the python imaging library to crop images to a specific size for a website. I have a problem, these images are meant to show people's faces so I need to automatically crop based on them.

I know face detection is a difficult concept so I'm thinking of using the face.com API http://developers.face.com/tools/#faces/detect which is fine for what I want to do.

I'm just a little stuck on how I would use this data to crop a select area based on the majority of faces.

Can anybody help?

Joe

Comment: If you want an API that you have more control over (for better or worse), look at OpenCV.  http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

Comment: I don't understand how I could get this to work with Python, and besides I don't expect to be uploading loads of photos in a short space of time.

Comment: There are Python wrappers for OpenCV, and a few blog posts on using it for face detection (e.g. http://creatingwithcode.com/howto/face-detection-in-static-images-with-python/) but if you have a solution that works fine, better to stick with that.  At a 5 second glance, OpenCV doesn't seem to give the face rotation (if desired).

Comment: I don't want too much load on a web server. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Eh, keep in mind for when your site starts getting millions of hits so you don't have to pay to use someone else's API :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a library for python that have a concept of smart-cropping that among other options, can use face detection to do a smarter cropping.
It uses opencv under the hood, but you are isolated from it.
https://github.com/globocom/thumbor

Answer (score 2):

If you have some rectangle that you want to excise from an image, here's what I might try first:

1. (optional) If the image is large, do a rough square crop centered on the face with dimensions `sqrt(2)` larger than the longer edge (if rectangular).  Worst-case (45° rotation), it will still grab everything important.
2. Rotate based on the face orientation (something like `rough_crop.rotate(math.degrees(math.atan(ydiff/xdiff))`, trig is fun)
3. Do a final crop.  If you did the initial crop, the face should be centered, otherwise you'll have to transform (rotate) all your old coordinates to the new image (more trig!).

Comment: the angle of rotation seems to be directly provided by the api as `roll` value, so we can go even without trig knowledge :)

Comment: That's good. I don't like trig (i've done it in school and don't really see how it works!).

I'll see what that does :)

Comment: @{Joe Simpson} oops, bad news.. i take it back.. roll, pitch and yaw seem to be 3D rotation coords :) so roll is probably not exactly 2D rotation angle

Comment: The API provides all three axes of rotation...`yaw`, `pitch`, and `roll`, so `roll` is probably a 3-D property, not a *direct* correlation to the face on the 2-D image.  In most circumstances though, they should be pretty close, and it's not like the value is exact anyways.

Comment: @mykhal Ugh, I type slow...  I'm thinking that if faces are generally pointed at the camera (huge assumption), `yaw` and `pitch` should be fairly small.

Comment: I will have to see what I can play around with :/